# How to initialize object without default constructor and heap usage?

Tags: c++, embedded

During programming an embedded system without MMU, I should not use heap (because of memory fragmentation problem).

Part of the software is written in *C* (drivers) and the logic is written in *C++* subset without dynamic allocation of memory.

Because of unit testing the default constructor is deleted. Instead - there is single parameter constructor with reference to structure of driver function pointers.

**driver.h:** (the pure C module)

```c
#pragma once
bool Init();
uint32_t ReadMeasurement();
```

**module.hpp:** (the C++ part)

```c++
class Module {
public:
  struct DriverApi {
    void (*Init)();
    uint32_t (*ReadData)();
  };

  Module() = delete;
  explicit Module(DriverApi &aDriverApi);

private:
  DriverApi& mDriverApi;
};
```

The module manager:

**module_manager.hpp:**

```c++
class ModuleManager {
//  (...)
private:
  Module::DriverApi module_1; // I can't declare this in this way
  Module::DriverApi module_2; // because of lack of default constructor.
  Module::DriverApi module_3;
  etc.
};
```

How to initialize `module_1`, `module_2` and `module_3` without using heap? And `n` parameters constructor?

**Options I'm aware:**

- It look's easy to use `std::shared_ptr`, but then `std::make_shared` *use heap*.
- I can leave default constructor and then call sth. like `Init(Module::DriverApi *aDriverApi)` but this *"violates" RAII*.

Is there any other way to create "elegant" and *embedded safe* initialization?

Comment: First define a `DriveApi` object, then use it to define the `Module` object? Can be done in any scope.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  What wrong with `Module::DriverAPI d; // do stuff with d; Module m(d);`?

Comment: If your class has no default constructor you need to call the other constructor. Can you explain why you think you need heap for that? (its not clear what problem you are trying to solve, even less what you seem to aim for as solution)

Comment: The question is very unclear. Are you asking how to implement the constructor?

Comment: RAII is not a law, it's a pattern that you use when it's suitable. You can't "violate" it.

Comment: Thanks @NathanOliver it was to obvious to see and I've overcomplicate the stuff.

Comment: Having `mDriverApi` be a reference seems odd.  Not wrong per say, but it certainly makes me wonder _why_.

Comment: @MilesBudnek I've done this because I'm sure that the mDriverApi can't be nullptr and I can pass the mocked driver instead of real driver.

Comment: `DriverApi` is just a bunch of function pointers, there is no big advantage of keeping a reference instead of a copy (but the usual downsides)

Comment: But you could do the same if `mDriverApi` was a value.  `Module realModule({&realInit, &realReadData})` for a real driver or `Module mockModule({&mockInit, &mockReadData})` for a mock driver.

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh, I didn't notice the constructor parameter was a non-const reference.  That should _also_ probably be a value or a reference-to-const unless there's some compelling reason for it to be otherwise.

Comment: Regarding the updated edit.  `Module::DriverApi module_1;` is fine.  It's a class member declaration, not an actual definition.  Nothing is being initialized right there.  It's in `ModuleManager`'s constructor where you actually initialize the members.

Comment: Thanks everyone for you valuable answers. Based on them I'll provide answer for my question soon.

Answer (score 1):

Either use a default constructor or write one with named parameters. If you need to initialize members to non-zero values but don't have access to such values because the constructor has too few parameters, the constructor is incorrectly designed.

> Because of unit testing the default constructor is deleted

Tests are supposed to make the product better - get rid of them if they do the opposite.

Normally any embedded system has a fixed set of drivers. So normally it would make little sense to have those as non-static members. Making a driver class per hardware peripheral present makes sense. Then a `static` instance for each instance of that hardware present on the target. You don't need to cover hardware which is never going to be present, nor will the hardware change dynamically in run-time. In fact a large part of it ought to be `const` and be stored in flash.

RAII has limited use on single core, single process embedded systems since your program needs to be deterministic and it owns all resources on the MCU. You usually never need to free up anything, all you need is to allocate as much memory as the product needs.

Keep it simple. Don't invent abstraction layers that fill no purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I just put your code in IDE, and it compiles.
What I can identify in your program:

1. if you try to assign `bool Init();` to the `void (*Init)()`, please change the return type.
2. When a user-defined constructor is defined, the default constructor is already deleted implicitly. What is missing is that you have to initialize the member.
   Try `explicit Module(DriverApi &aDriverApi):mDriverApi{aDriverApi}{}`

   ```
    class Module {
    public:
        struct DriverApi {
            void (*Init)();
            uint32_t (*ReadData)();
        };

        Module() = delete;
        explicit Module(DriverApi &aDriverApi):mDriverApi{aDriverApi}{}

    private:
        DriverApi& mDriverApi;
    };


    void fun(){
        std::cout<<"This is fun\n";
    }

    int main(){

        Module::DriverApi module_1; // I can't declare this in this way because of lack of default constructor.

        module_1.Init = fun;
        module_1.Init();

        Module m{module_1};

        return 0;
    }
   ```